# Adding buttons to a search view

Tags: android

I want to implement a layout similar to the one on google maps search bar:

[image: google maps search bar]

I am using a [`SearchView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) in my layout. Now I would like to know how to add buttons to the view. Like the directions and voice search buttons on GMaps.

How do I get that?

Comment: I think in Google Maps, they just put the searchView inside an actionbar, then put the direction and voice buttons inside the actionbar and next to the searchView.